# QA Issue: Package version for package went backwards which would break package feeds [version-going-backwards]

Tags: linux, build, yocto, recipe, yocto-recipe

I'm trying to build a `core-image-minimal` image using an updated recipe of Yocto 3.1 (pytest from 5.x.x to 6.x.x) that has been successfully builded with `devtool build`. The work has been added to a custom layer with priority 6 but I'm unable to compile the image because at the end the following errors are encountered

```
ERROR: python3-pytest-5.3.5-r0 do_packagedata: QA Issue: Package version for package python3-pytest-src went backwards which would break package feeds (from 0:6.2.4-r0 to 0:5.3.5-r0) [version-going-backwards]
ERROR: python3-pytest-5.3.5-r0 do_packagedata: QA Issue: Package version for package python3-pytest-dbg went backwards which would break package feeds (from 0:6.2.4-r0 to 0:5.3.5-r0) [version-going-backwards]
ERROR: python3-pytest-5.3.5-r0 do_packagedata: QA Issue: Package version for package python3-pytest-staticdev went backwards which would break package feeds (from 0:6.2.4-r0 to 0:5.3.5-r0) [version-going-backwards]
ERROR: python3-pytest-5.3.5-r0 do_packagedata: QA Issue: Package version for package python3-pytest-dev went backwards which would break package feeds (from 0:6.2.4-r0 to 0:5.3.5-r0) [version-going-backwards]
ERROR: python3-pytest-5.3.5-r0 do_packagedata: QA Issue: Package version for package python3-pytest-doc went backwards which would break package feeds (from 0:6.2.4-r0 to 0:5.3.5-r0) [version-going-backwards]
ERROR: python3-pytest-5.3.5-r0 do_packagedata: QA Issue: Package version for package python3-pytest-locale went backwards which would break package feeds (from 0:6.2.4-r0 to 0:5.3.5-r0) [version-going-backwards]
ERROR: python3-pytest-5.3.5-r0 do_packagedata: QA Issue: Package version for package python3-pytest went backwards which would break package feeds (from 0:6.2.4-r0 to 0:5.3.5-r0) [version-going-backwards]
ERROR: core-image-minimal-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: The postinstall intercept hook 'update_gtk_icon_cache' failed, details in /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/build_fb/tmp/work/imx6ul_var_dart-fslc-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/build_fb/tmp/work/imx6ul_var_dart-fslc-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.13259
ERROR: Task (/home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
```

Is that related to layers priorities? I noticed that the `meta-python` layer that provides the `pytest` recipe (5.x.x) got an higher priority over mine layer. If not what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors:

1. The fatal QA Issue (because it is in `ERROR_QA`).

The highest available version should be selected. The behaviour might be changed by [variable DEFAULT_PREFERENCE](http://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-DEFAULT_PREFERENCE) or [variable PREFERRED_VERSION](http://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-PREFERRED_VERSION). Also check output of `bitbake-layers` and its subcommands `show-recipes`, `show-overlayed` and maybe `show-appends`. There might be something useful.

2. Failure of postinstall hook

See the line:

```
ERROR: core-image-minimal-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: The postinstall intercept hook 'update_gtk_icon_cache' failed, details in /home/cladm1/var-fslc-yocto/build_fb/tmp/work/imx6ul_var_dart-fslc-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs
```

The problem is failure of the postinstall hook. There are some solutions (or workarounds?) on the Internet. Also check the mentioned logfile.

Edit: I was wrong in my first answer, the `version-going-backwards` is treated as error.